# How To Customize MODX Articles Generated Archives/Tags Pages?

Tags: php, templates, modx, google-search-console

I've installed the MODX Articles plugin to build blog pages. However, I need a way to modify the generated pages for the filters like Author, Tags, and Archives.

At the moment, the pages generate the same output as the Container template with the RowTpl that matches the criteria.

The issue with this is duplicate `meta`, `description`, and `title` tags. Google Webmaster sees this as an issue.

A simple solution would be to add a heading placeholder in the template to display the clicked category. Where do I need to look to edit this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of template variables for your SEO meta tags and assign them to your article template. In fact, this is a good way to control all your meta information site wide.

[Template Variable Docs.](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/template-variables)

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question. Meta tag template variables are already in place in the actual article page. I am referring to generated pages by articles which do not even have templates. The 'archives' and 'tags' generated pages.

Answer (score 0):

In my 5 years of MODX experience, Articles could be a really pain in the ass, in many ways. I suggest you to make use of normal resources and use the following add-ons so everything 'looks' like Articles:

- [Grid Class Key](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/gridclasskey) to show the resources in the back-end like Articles does (You can show the number of comments and used tags in the list of articles, for example)
- [Archivist](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/archivist), if you want to have year/month/day url's
- [SmartTag](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/smarttag) and [Taglister](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/taglister) for tagging
- [Quip](http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/quip), which you already installed. It plays nice with normal resources and Grid Class Key too.

This way you are way more flexible.

Let me know if you need more info or sample code.